# Library function to find difference between two lists - OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there a library function to find `List1 minus elements that appear in List2`?  I've been googling around and haven't found much.

It doesn't seem *too* trivial to write it myself. I've written a function to remove a specific element from a list but that's much more simple:

```
let rec difference l arg = match l with
| [] -> []
| x :: xs -> 
    if (x = arg) then difference xs arg
    else x :: difference xs arg;;
```

Comment: There is Set [diff](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html), but that doesn't maintain ordering or multiplicity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will this do?

```
let diff l1 l2 = List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x l2)) l1
```

Comment: This computes the intersection of the lists. You are missing `not`, I think. (This is probably an assignment, so no harm done really.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield yeah, didn't know that `-` was dash, I thought it was some kind of indicator. edited my answer and the question

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up actually doing was just writing another function which would call the first one I posted

```
let rec difference l arg = match l with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> 
        if (x = arg) then difference xs arg
        else x :: difference xs arg;; 

let rec list_diff l1 l2 = match l2 with
    | [] -> l1
    | x :: xs -> list_diff (difference l1 x) xs;;
```

Although the solution I accepted is much more elegant

Comment: This soultions doesn't seem to be completely correct.   This only finds what is not in list 1 (l1).  That is, list_diff [3;4;5] [2;3;6];; returns  [4; 5] not [4;5;6]