# How to fix this 'Difference of two lists' function?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

This question is related to [Library function to find difference between two lists - OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132458/library-function-to-find-difference-between-two-lists-ocaml). I wanted to write my own function, different from these here. I use built-in higher order functions. Here's my code:

```
let listdifference l1 l2=
List.fold_left (fun x y ->List.filter (fun x->x!=y) l1) [] l2;;
```

I know that this is not so good. The problem is because I have `l1` as an argument in `List.filter` argument, so as an output I get a list without just one element of the second list. But I don't know how to fix it. Any help?

Comment: Note that the operator `!=` is the negation of `==`, which checks for physical equality.
The negeation of `=` is `<>`, which i think you should use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **map** the list with your function

```ml
let diffList l1 l2 = 
    List.filter (fun x -> List.fold_left (&&) true @@ List.map (fun t -> t != x) l2) l1;;
```

Which is actually equivalent to :

```ml
let diffList l1 l2 = 
    List.filter (fun x -> List.for_all (fun t -> t != x) l2) l1;;
```

Which is the same as

```ml
let diffList l1 l2 = 
    List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x l2)) l1;;
```

Answer (score 0):

About the function you pass as first parameter to `List.fold_left`, it might be easier if you use more explicit names. I usually use `acc` for the accumulator.

Moreover, you're using twice the variable name `x`: the outer one is thus *shadowed* by the inner one in expression `x!=y`.

With a simple renaming we would have the following code equivalent to yours:

```
List.fold_left (fun acc elt_from_l2 -> List.filter (fun elt_from_l1 -> elt_from_l1 != elt_from_l2 ) l1) [] l2
```

Here we can see that the accumulator is never used, which seems to be the issue.

Comment: I think it doesn't work: [1;2;2;6;3;9;1;4;6] [2;3] -> [1; 2; 2; 6; 9; 1; 4; 6]

Comment: sure! that's what I meant by "Here we can see that the accumulator is never used, which seems to be the issue." Did you ask for help, or just for someone to give an answer that you can then copy/paste?